# How do I stop Ubuntu from suggesting to upgrade to a non-LTS release?

Tags: 12.04, partial-upgrade

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. As of recently I started getting message that I need to upgrade the system in order to install new kernel. Look at the image.

[image]

However, during this upgrade they will remove some of tools which I do not want to be removed.

The same thing happened a few months ago and I upgraded to install kernel and as of then some Java apps stopped working, especially those who were depended on 32bit libraries I forcibly installed.

How to stop this happening? Why are they forcing me to upgrade when 12.04 was supposed to be LTS?

Comment: How do you exactly forced 32bit libraries?

Comment: Some java apps from a specific web service tools needed them. So I previously installed them using --force or similar switch. I can't remember at this point since I followed online tutorial.

Comment: That is not really helpful.... and the package for 32bit libraries is ia32-libs-multiarch , I don't see why you needed to force install.

Comment: It's not important now. They are gone with the last kernel upgrade. Can you help me with this one?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo aptitude hold packagename` on the packages you are trying to preserve?

Comment: no since I did not upgrade manually. this screen came by default.

Comment: Sorry, I just reread your question. Is it actually "How do I stop Ubuntu from suggesting to upgrade to a non-LTS release?" ?

Comment: @alexander255 Yes. I will change the title.

Comment: There you go :-)

Comment: @alexander255 Hahaha immediate replies

Comment: @ubuntico A strange feeling, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the Dash (By pressing the "Super-Key" / "Windows-Key" / "Ubuntu-Key" / "Command-Key")
2. Search for "Software"
3. Open the application "Software & Updates"
4. Select the "Updates" tab
5. Next to "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" select "For long-term support versions": [image: Software & Updates]
6. Enter your password and press enter
7. Close the "Software & Updates" application
8. Allow the system to search for updates: [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "Software & Updates"
2. Select "Updates" tab.
3. At that tab, there is an option says "Notify me of a new version"
4. Open the list and choose "For long term support versions"

You will only get notified for LTS updates from now on.

Answer (score 0):

**So what was the problem?**

Well it is easy to configure upgrade the way you want.

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and execute `software-properties-gtk`.
- It will open **Software Sources** window. Go to <kbd>Updates</kbd> tab and set the value for **Notify me for new Ubuntu version:** to <kbd>For long term support versions</kbd>.
- If you want to stop the upgradation message, set **Automatically check for Updates:** to <kbd>Never</kbd>
- Then <kbd>Close</kbd> the window and upgrade your repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

That's all. Reply if you need any further assistance..